# Angular 7 Add an extension method to primitives

Tags: angular, extension-methods, typescript-typings, angular7

I would like to add few methods to primitives.
I have the following file:

**string-extension.ts:**

```
interface String {
    isNullOrEmpty(this: string): boolean;
}

String.prototype.isNullOrEmpty = function (this: string): boolean {
    return !this;
};
```

I have a component which has the following code:

```
constructor () {
    let a = "asd";
    alert(a.isNullOrEmpty());
}
```

no import is added at the top.
When I run the client, it crashes on that line.

```
a.isNullOrEmpty is not a function
```

When I inspect the code, i see that my string-extension.ts file wasn't included there.
I am very familiar with the concept in C# but im not quite familiar with it in TypeScript, so if you need more info, ill provide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

first, create `global .d.ts.` file to set up the signature.

**global.d.ts.**

```
export {}; // this file needs to be a module
declare global {
  interface String {
        isNullOrEmpty(this: string): boolean;
  }
}
```

**string-extension.ts:**

```
export {}; // this file needs to be a module
String.prototype.isNullOrEmpty = function (this: string): boolean {
    return !this;
};
```

Now in the `main.ts` import the extension

```
 import './string-extension'
```

Comment: src/global.d.ts(1,9): error TS2669: Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.

Comment: yeah. saw that too in someone's answer and it worked. thanks alot

Comment: I also think, it might be smart to mention where the `global.d.ts` file should be placed. If I am not mistaken, this should be in the root of the Angular project, right?